# How to transform between horizontal and equatorial coordinates?

Tags: radio-astronomy, coordinate-systems

I want to express the transformation between horizontal (azimuth $A$,elevation/altitude $\varepsilon$) coordinates and equatorial (hourangle $H$/right ascension $\alpha$, declination $\delta$) as a mathematical, algebraic relation. I've been checking around the internet and everywhere the relationship shown below (from the textbook Interferometry and Synthesis in Radioastronomy) is given. [Here is another version of the explanation](http://math_research.uct.ac.za/%7Esiphelo/admin/interferometry/3_Positional_Astronomy/3_3_Horizontal_Coordinates.html).

However, since (for horizontal $A,\varepsilon$ to equatorial $H,\delta$) we should know the latitude $L$ and the coordinates $A,\varepsilon$ we want to transform, the system ends up overdetermined and there is no solution. Check for $A=39.7$°, $\varepsilon=21.6$°, and $L=-33.27$.

However, this is the relationship I encounter when I want to know the formulae. Thankfully I can do what I want to do by utilising AstroPy and other tools. How is this system of equations meant to be used?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not overdetermined, you need $\cos A, \sin A$ in order to determine the correct quadrant.  It is actually more convenient to rewrite them in terms of $\tan A$ so that you can use the atan2 function provided in most programming languages. See: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/convert_ra_dec_to_alt_az.html

Comment: Try and find Astronomical Algorithms, by Jean Meeus. It explains very well how to convert from one system of coordinates to another.